# Making a chat application

Tags: c#, sockets, chat

I'm using sockets to make a C# chat application, where users can connect to one user that hosts a server, and send messages to it.

Now, the problem is that: While the users can send data to the server, and the data will be displayed in the server, the data WON'T be displayed to other users whose clients are connected to the server.

The current chat is a simple TCP protocol packet transfer. The only problem is sending data back to the client.

So my question is, how can I make the server broadcast messages to all clients?

```
namespace Client
{
    class Program
    {
        static Socket sck;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 1234);
            sck.Connect(localEndPoint);
            Console.Write("Enter Text: ");
            string text = Console.ReadLine();
            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
            sck.Send(data);
            Main(args);
        }
    }
}

namespace Server
{
    class Program
    {
        static byte[] Buffer { get; set; }
        static byte[] formatted;
        static Socket sck;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            listen();
        }
        public static void listen()
        {
            sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            sck.Bind(new IPEndPoint(0, 1234));
            sck.Listen(1);

            Socket accepted = sck.Accept();
            Buffer = new byte[accepted.SendBufferSize];
            int bytesRead = accepted.Receive(Buffer);
            formatted = new byte[bytesRead];
            for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
            {
                formatted[i] = Buffer[i];
            }
            string strData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(formatted);
            Console.Write(strData + "\r\n");
            sck.Close();
            accepted.Close();
            listen();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd have to keep a list of connected clients, i.e. `List<Socket>` or a custom structure and then iterate over the collection and `.Send` the message to all clients.

Comment: listen() is recursive?  That's not gonna end well...

Comment: @darren you should have answer this question and not comment because your answer is correct.

Comment: OK Darren, thanks, but how do I display the message on the clients? Should I listen on the clients too for a message?

Comment: Oh wait - the client is recursive as well.  Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Martin, this is temporary. While the call stack is surely finite, it can hold quite a lot of calls. So right now that's not the important matter. I'll just add a while loop later on.

Comment: @BlueRay010 - it's a little more complex than just stack use.  You will only be able to make a receive call on one client at a time  - the latest one to connect.  All the others will be ignored and they will time out on their send calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen() listens for incoming connection requests.  On the server, you'll have to keep a list of connections and distribute messages that it has received back to waiting clients in the list.  On the client, you'll have to set up code to receive those messages with the socket that you used to connect to the server.  It's two way.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s4y8aff(v=vs.110).aspx

EDIT:

I presume that you know calling back into your Main() function is not good practice.  If you didn't then you should consider using a loop to start off with, and adding some trigger to exit the loop.